# How to find approximate value of $1.01e^{1.01({0.99) }^2} $?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, approximation

I want to find the approximate value of  $1.01e^{1.01({0.99) }^2}$  by using derivative. 
I tried choosing x=1 and $\delta x=0.01$ it didnt work. How can I start?

Comment: What function do you use?

Comment: $xe^{x(x^2-0.04)}$

Comment: So you use $x=1, \delta x=0.01, f(x)=$ the formula you write, it gives you $1.01e^{1.01(1.01^2-0.04)}$, different from the one in the title.

Comment: $x^{x(x^2-0.04)}$ is not strictly right, but it is close enough.  It should be $xe^{x(x-0.02)^2}=xe^{x(x^2-0.04x+0.0016)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $f(x)=(1+x)e^{(1+x)(1-x)^2}$, $f(0.01)\approx f(0)+0.01f'(0)$

Comment: Any reason to downvote?

Comment: I dont know why it got downvoted.it seems correct to me f(0)=e and f'(0)=0

Answer (score 3):

Following frank000:  Take a Taylor series of $f(x) = (1+x) e^{(1+x)(1-x)^2}$ around $x = 0$:

$e-\frac{3 e \delta ^2}{2}+\frac{4 e \delta ^3}{3}+\frac{7 e \delta ^4}{8}-\frac{9 e
   \delta ^5}{5}+O\left(\delta ^6\right)$

and substitute $\delta \to 0.01$ to find:

$2.71788$, which is also the value given by *Mathematica* for the explicit computation in the title.